# Difficulties to prove that a function is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Is the positive function $f(x) = \frac{{{x^D}}}{{x - A}}$ defined in $]A, + \infty[$ with $A \ge 1$ and $D > 1$ a convex function for all these $A$ and $D$ ?
I think so but I have a hard time proving it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to compute $f''(x)$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Studying the sign of the second derivative becomes prohibitive due to the calculations with $A$ and $D$. 
The product of two positive functions, convex and with the "same monotony" is a convex function, but $x^D$ is increasing and $\frac{1}{{x - A}}$ is decreaising.

Comment: $D=2$ is a known case

Answer (score 0):

It is not always convex, as demonstrated by [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x4cexf7yci). If it were convex, then the purple dot should have been above the red one.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Now I think that the function is not convex for $ 1 < D <2 $.